# Connecting EC2 with Default VPC vs Customized VPC in AWS Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using default VPC in AWS to connect my tf code and it is working fine there.
When i use my own customized VPC and along with that private and public subnets and security groups.
it gives me error mentioned in the link.

[image]

I have used below code so far.

```
 resource "aws_instance" "ec2_public" {
  count         = var.instance_public_count
  instance_type = var.public_size
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.example.name, ]
  }
```

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_private" {
  count         = var.instance_private_count
  instance_type = var.private_size
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.example.name, ]
   }
```

```
resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name        = "allow_specified_ports"
  vpc_id      = "vpc-xyz"
  description = "ports"
```

```
# Inbound rules
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.security_group_ports
    content {
      from_port   = ingress.value
      to_port     = ingress.value
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```

```
# Outbound Rules
  tags = {
    Name = "*"
  }
}
variable "instance_private_count" {
  type = number
}
variable "instance_public_count" {
  type = number
}
variable "public_subnet_id" {
  type = string
}
variable "private_subnet_id" {
  type = string
}
variable "security_group_id" {
  type = string
}
```

Comment: The code from the screenshot and the code you have added to the question are different.

Comment: @MarkoE apologies, actually some part of the code was written by other developer. that's why i omitted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the configuration for creating EC2 instances which only applies in certain use cases. This is the offending part:

```
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.example.name,
  ]
```

As per the documentation [1]:

> `security_groups` - (Optional, EC2-Classic and default VPC only) List of security group names to associate with.

As you can see, since you moved away from the default VPC, it does not work anymore. However, to fix this, you need to use `vpc_security_group_ids` instead:

> If you are creating Instances in a VPC, use `vpc_security_group_ids` instead.

That means you need to fix the code to look like the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "public" {
  count                  = var.instance_public_count
  instance_type          = var.public_size
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.example.id,]
 }

resource "aws_instance" "private" {
  count                  = var.instance_private_count
  instance_type          = var.private_size
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.example.id,]
}
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#security_groups

Comment: **Now i am getting below error.**
**in above my question code**
**i have edit the code in Question**
│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
│       status code: 400, request id: xyz
││   with aws_instance.public[1],
│   on Assig-2.tf line 21, in resource "aws_instance" "public":
│   21: resource "aws_instance" "public" {

Comment: That should be a different question. It is no longer the same as the one in the original question.

Comment: I have only added the suggested code line in my code. I have edit the code as you have suggested (i have updated the edit code in original Question) for your kind reference.

Comment: Fixed, it should have been the ID of the security group, not name.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for telling me about the error, you were right.